# Отображение времени выполнения программы в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Как при выполнении программы выводить в PyCharm время, затраченное на выполнение программы?

Answer (score 0):

Уже отвечали на этот вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656239/how-do-i-time-script-execution-time-in-pycharm-without-adding-code-every-time

[image: 1]

Рядом с кнопкой дебага можно вызвать cProfile. Подробный результат выполнения показывается как на скриншоте выше.